# Open mailto links in its default email composer

Tags: html, mailto

Hi
i want to send mail, and it has a mailto html link, and i want that when someone clicks on that link it should open in the same email service provider.. like if mail is received on gmail, so it should open gmail composer for mailto link, same for yahoo and others....I dont want to open outlook on mailto links...

please help me

Comment: You mean on your own computer? That would be off-topic here. Voting to migrate to superuser.com

Comment: If it's on your computer, then then should be moved to superuser. If you want to put this in a page, you'd can't use the default mailto link to point to gmail or yahoo as far as I know. You can directly link to it so that it opens up the web app and goes to the compose screen, but it would be only for one web app at a time. Not generic

Comment: i had sort it out, actually i cant be done....

Comment: when the mailto link is in the mailbox.. it automatically open with its default composer... it doesnt works offline :P

Answer (score 0):

This may not fit all your requirements but here's what worked for me. I wanted mailto links to open in my Yahoo Mail on Chrome.

Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Set Default Programs

In the list that appears on the left of the window click on Google Chrome

Then click on the link "Choose defaults for this program" that appears at the bottom of the window.

In the next window to appear, under the Protocols section click on the MAILTO checkbox to select it, then click the save button at lower right.